# TCPDF unable to handle “\00a0” unicode character non breakable space

Tags: php, unicode, tcpdf

I am converting an HTML string to PDF. The HTML string has a Unicode character `\00a0` non breakable space. In the PDF, `\00a0` is converted in to `;Â` symbols.

Below is the code

```
$pdf = new \TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, false, 'UTF-8', false);
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('helvetica', '', 11, '', true);
$pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');
$pdf->Ln(2);
$pdfDoc = $pdf->Output("doc.pdf", "F");
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

UTF-8 `U+00A0` string is `1100 0010 1010 0000` in binary (`C2 A0` in hex).
Similarly, Latin-1 (ISO_IEC 8859-1) `Â`  string is `1100 0010 1010 0000` in binary too.

I think that your converter read that UTF-8 html file as Latin-1.

See:
[ISO_IEC 8859-1 - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).